# Apache Echart - Heatmap and highlight action on event : how to hightlight data for a specific value of X?

Tags: javascript, charts, apache-echarts

Considering the Apache Echart library and this example : https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=heatmap-cartesian

If I add the following code snippet :

```
myChart.on('click', function (params) {
    myChart.dispatchAction({
        type: 'highlight',
        seriesIndex: [0],
    });
});
```

It allows the user to click on a data of the heatmap and it will hightlight all data.

The hightlight action (https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#action) can be used with seriesIndex, seriesId and seriesName. However, heatmap are built with only one serie of data.

How could I proceed to hightlight only one line (or one value of X, or one day of the week-end) when I click on a value belonging to this line ?
For exemple, how can I highlight all data for 'Monday' if I click a data associated with 'Monday'.

I have been trying to play around and :

- working with multiple series instead of one breaks the heatmap behavior.
- I can get more details about where I click with the params variable of the event listener. I could find an algorythm that focus only data of the line I focus on, but anyway the dispatchAction 'highlight' works only for the whole serie.

****TLDR** : With Apache Echart and the heatmap type of plot, how can I use highlight action toward a single value of X (or heatmap line) ?**

Answer (score 1):

You can select specific items from the series by setting the `dataIndex` in the call action object,
see the the api docs for [`action.highlight`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#action.highlight).

The `dataIndex` of the clicked item may be retrieved from `params.dataIndex`, where `params`
is the argument in the `click` handler you defined; also useful are the corresponding `x` and `y`
components, from `params.data` (`[x, y] = params.data`).

The `dataIndex` is simply the index of the item's data in the series `data` array;
`params.seriesIndex` may be used to identify the series, especially if there is more than one.

An example handler that selects a line, that is all the items with the same `y` value as the clicked item, (the same day of the week):

```js
myChart.on('click', function (params) {
    const data = myChart.getOption().series[params.seriesIndex].data;
    const [x, y] = params.data;
    // get all indices of data with the same y (day of the week)
    const dataIndex = data.map(([xData, yData, value], idx) => y === yData && Number.isFinite(value) ? idx : null).
    filter(v => v !== null);
    myChart.dispatchAction({
        type: 'highlight',
        seriesIndex: [0],
        dataIndex
    });
});
```

Snippet:

```js
const myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

// prettier-ignore
const hours = [
    '12a', '1a', '2a', '3a', '4a', '5a', '6a',
    '7a', '8a', '9a', '10a', '11a',
    '12p', '1p', '2p', '3p', '4p', '5p',
    '6p', '7p', '8p', '9p', '10p', '11p'
];
// prettier-ignore
const days = [
    'Saturday', 'Friday', 'Thursday',
    'Wednesday', 'Tuesday', 'Monday', 'Sunday'
];
// prettier-ignore
const data = [[0, 0, 5], [0, 1, 1], [0, 2, 0], [0, 3, 0], [0, 4, 0], [0, 5, 0], [0, 6, 0], [0, 7, 0], [0, 8, 0], [0, 9, 0], [0, 10, 0], [0, 11, 2], [0, 12, 4], [0, 13, 1], [0, 14, 1], [0, 15, 3], [0, 16, 4], [0, 17, 6], [0, 18, 4], [0, 19, 4], [0, 20, 3], [0, 21, 3], [0, 22, 2], [0, 23, 5], [1, 0, 7], [1, 1, 0], [1, 2, 0], [1, 3, 0], [1, 4, 0], [1, 5, 0], [1, 6, 0], [1, 7, 0], [1, 8, 0], [1, 9, 0], [1, 10, 5], [1, 11, 2], [1, 12, 2], [1, 13, 6], [1, 14, 9], [1, 15, 11], [1, 16, 6], [1, 17, 7], [1, 18, 8], [1, 19, 12], [1, 20, 5], [1, 21, 5], [1, 22, 7], [1, 23, 2], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 0], [2, 3, 0], [2, 4, 0], [2, 5, 0], [2, 6, 0], [2, 7, 0], [2, 8, 0], [2, 9, 0], [2, 10, 3], [2, 11, 2], [2, 12, 1], [2, 13, 9], [2, 14, 8], [2, 15, 10], [2, 16, 6], [2, 17, 5], [2, 18, 5], [2, 19, 5], [2, 20, 7], [2, 21, 4], [2, 22, 2], [2, 23, 4], [3, 0, 7], [3, 1, 3], [3, 2, 0], [3, 3, 0], [3, 4, 0], [3, 5, 0], [3, 6, 0], [3, 7, 0], [3, 8, 1], [3, 9, 0], [3, 10, 5], [3, 11, 4], [3, 12, 7], [3, 13, 14], [3, 14, 13], [3, 15, 12], [3, 16, 9], [3, 17, 5], [3, 18, 5], [3, 19, 10], [3, 20, 6], [3, 21, 4], [3, 22, 4], [3, 23, 1], [4, 0, 1], [4, 1, 3], [4, 2, 0], [4, 3, 0], [4, 4, 0], [4, 5, 1], [4, 6, 0], [4, 7, 0], [4, 8, 0], [4, 9, 2], [4, 10, 4], [4, 11, 4], [4, 12, 2], [4, 13, 4], [4, 14, 4], [4, 15, 14], [4, 16, 12], [4, 17, 1], [4, 18, 8], [4, 19, 5], [4, 20, 3], [4, 21, 7], [4, 22, 3], [4, 23, 0], [5, 0, 2], [5, 1, 1], [5, 2, 0], [5, 3, 3], [5, 4, 0], [5, 5, 0], [5, 6, 0], [5, 7, 0], [5, 8, 2], [5, 9, 0], [5, 10, 4], [5, 11, 1], [5, 12, 5], [5, 13, 10], [5, 14, 5], [5, 15, 7], [5, 16, 11], [5, 17, 6], [5, 18, 0], [5, 19, 5], [5, 20, 3], [5, 21, 4], [5, 22, 2], [5, 23, 0], [6, 0, 1], [6, 1, 0], [6, 2, 0], [6, 3, 0], [6, 4, 0], [6, 5, 0], [6, 6, 0], [6, 7, 0], [6, 8, 0], [6, 9, 0], [6, 10, 1], [6, 11, 0], [6, 12, 2], [6, 13, 1], [6, 14, 3], [6, 15, 4], [6, 16, 0], [6, 17, 0], [6, 18, 0], [6, 19, 0], [6, 20, 1], [6, 21, 2], [6, 22, 2], [6, 23, 6]]
    .map(function (item) {
        return [item[1], item[0], item[2] || '-'];
    });

const option = {
    tooltip: {
        position: 'top'
    },
    grid: {
        height: '50%',
        top: '10%'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: hours,
        splitArea: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        data: days,
        splitArea: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    visualMap: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10,
        calculable: true,
        orient: 'horizontal',
        left: 'center',
        bottom: '15%'
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Punch Card',
            type: 'heatmap',
            data: data,
            label: {
                show: true
            },
            emphasis: {
                itemStyle: {
                    shadowBlur: 10,
                    shadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
                }
            }
        }
    ]
};

option && myChart.setOption(option);

myChart.on('click', function (params) {
    const seriesIndex = params.seriesIndex,
        data = myChart.getOption().series[seriesIndex].data;
    const [x, y] = params.data;
    // get all indices of data with the same y (day of the week)
    const dataIndex = data.map(([xData, yData, value], idx) => y === yData && Number.isFinite(value) ? idx : null).filter(v => v !== null);
    myChart.dispatchAction({
        type: 'highlight',
        seriesIndex,
        dataIndex
    });
});
```

```css
#main {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.4.2/echarts.min.js" integrity="sha512-VdqgeoWrVJcsDXFlQEKqE5MyhaIgB9yXUVaiUa8DR2J4Lr1uWcFm+ZH/YnzV5WqgKf4GPyHQ64vVLgzqGIchyw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this very complete answer, I have found the dataIndex option desperately looking at the doc one last time.

Comment: Now I realize I had to think about getting rid of the highlight... :D

Comment: TIL, [action.downplay](https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#action.downplay) appears to be the opposite of highlight

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snippet that highlights a line of the heatmap and that also downplay (opposite of highlight) an hypothetical previously clicked line :

```
myChart.on('click', function (params) {
if (event.target) {
    myChart.dispatchAction({
        type: 'downplay',
        seriesIndex: [0],
    });
    const seriesIndex = params.seriesIndex,
        data = myChart.getOption().series[seriesIndex].data;
    const [x, y] = params.data;
    const dataIndex = data.map(([xData, yData, value], idx) => y === yData && Number.isFinite(value) ? idx : null).filter(v => v !== null);
    myChart.dispatchAction({
        type: 'highlight',
        seriesIndex,
        dataIndex
    });
}
```

Then another code snippet that's downplay any highlighted line if you click somewhere out of heatmap (but on plot zone of course) :

```
myChart.getZr().on('click', function (event) {
if (!event.target) {
    myChart.dispatchAction({
        type: 'downplay',
        seriesIndex: [0],
    });
}
});
```